# Is there a product to auto-build indexes based on slow queries?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, index-tuning

I'm looking to either find, purchase, or write a script to identify slow queries, identify potential missing indexes, and when needed create the appropriate index within a reasonable amount of time of identifying the potential index. Anyone know of a product or capability that does it?

Thanks

Comment: Having a tool to autobuild indexes would be impractical. Why? Over the course of time, the distribution and cardinality of keys within an index can change. That could make indexes built in the past obsolete, even if your recomputed the index statistics. That calls for additional automatic management to drop such outdated indexes. The posted answer from @BillKarwin lets you keep an eye on your data (to anticipate any key distribution changes) and your application (changing data retrieval algorithms or improving its efficiency).

Comment: I think this is totally practical. The problems @RolandoMySQLDBA point out can be part of a periodic index analysis. I think this is an overdue feature that would be quite popular.

Comment: Provide the query here; I am working on such a tool, but it still has flaws that need my supervision.  I find that most (not all) indexes do not become obsolete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no product that does what you describe automatically. At least not for MySQL.

There are tools that identify slow queries, and even run EXPLAIN automatically, for example [pt-query-digest](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-query-digest.html). But deciding on the right indexes is up to you. There are too many exception cases where you might choose to create a different index, or avoid creating the recommended index, regardless of the advice of the tool.

You might like to read my presentation, [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really). It's not that hard to learn to do it.